# Why does this python code execute faster when in a function?

Tags: python, performance, function

I developed the following Python code to solve [Project Euler problem #187](https://projecteuler.net/problem=187), which runs correctly, but averages about 11 seconds per run. `generatePrimes` runs the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) on the odd numbers and returns all primes (does not include `2`)

```
from utilities import generatePrimes
from time import perf_counter_ns

limit = 100000000

start = perf_counter_ns()

primes = generatePrimes(limit // 2)
answer = len(primes) + 1
for p in primes:
    for q in primes:
        if q > p or p * q >= limit:
            break
        answer += 1

end = perf_counter_ns()

print("Answer: {}".format(answer))
print("Calculated in {} seconds".format((end - start) / 1000000000))
```

Before I planned to optimize it, I decided to move it to a function to make the code clearer, as follows. Notice how the code is nearly identical, adjusted to be in a function.

```
from utilities import generatePrimes
from time import perf_counter_ns


def solve(limit: int):
    primes = generatePrimes(limit // 2)
    total = len(primes) + 1
    for p in primes:
        for q in primes:
            if q > p or p * q >= limit:
                break
            total += 1
    return total


start = perf_counter_ns()
answer = solve(100000000)
end = perf_counter_ns()

print("Answer: {}".format(answer))
print("Calculated in {} seconds".format((end - start) / 1000000000))
```

However, it now runs in an average of **9** seconds. Placing the initialization of `start` before the function definition has no noticeable effect on the time. **Why does placing this code inside a function result in better performance?**